# WordPres how to display the value of a variable from function.php file in my custom page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

With this chunk of `JavaScript` code, I add, fetch, and pass the ID of the post (like an array) to the `function.php` file.

```
  const nonRegister = document.querySelectorAll('.non-register')
  nonRegister.forEach(item=>{
  item.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let postNumber = item.getAttribute('data-post-id');
    let myFavoriteArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems") || "[]");
    let retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("favoriteItems");
    let retrievedDataArray = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    if(retrievedDataArray !== null && retrievedDataArray.includes(postNumber)){
        alert('This model has already been added to favorites')
    }else{
        myFavoriteArray.push(postNumber);
        localStorage.setItem("favoriteItems", JSON.stringify(myFavoriteArray));
        let forConversion = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
        data = {
            'action': 'vicso_non_register',
            'forConversion': forConversion,
        }
            jQuery.ajax({
               type:'post',
               url: object_url.url,
               data: data,
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
                 console.log(data)
               }
           });
         }
      })
   })
```

This is my code in a `function.php` file.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );

function vicso_non_register(){

    $favorite_array    = $_POST['forConversion'];
    echo   $test = json_encode(array('favorite_array'=>$favorite_array));

    die;
}
```

But how do I get to the array that the function returns? I need a PHP array with these data on the `fav_models.php` for example.

If someone can suggest, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sending data back as the ajax response in json format**:

You could use wordpress `wp_send_json_success` and `wp_send_json_error` functions.

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );

function vicso_non_register(){

    $favorite_array    = sanitize_text_field($_POST['forConversion']);
  
    wp_send_json_success($favorite_array); 

   // or you could send it via  "wp_send_json_error", if you need to!
}
```

And on the front end, you could `console.log` the response returned from `function.php`.

You could read more about these two functions on the documentation page.

> [WordPress `wp_send_json_success` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/)
> [WordPress `wp_send_json_error` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/)

---

**Sending data to another page**:

There are multiple ways to do it, you could `localize your script` or I'd prefer to send it as a `query_var`/`query string`.

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_vicso_non_register', 'vicso_non_register' );

function vicso_non_register(){

    $favorite_array    = sanitize_text_field($_POST['forConversion']);

    wp_send_json_success($favorite_array); // send the data back to the ajax call
  
    if(!empty($favorite_array)){
      wp_safe_redirect(site_url('/fav_models.php/?favorite='.$favorite_array));
      exit;
    }
    
}
```

Then on the "fav_models.php" you could access that value by using this:

```php
$new_page_variable = isset($_GET["favorite"]) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET["favorite"]) : ""
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but sorry, but I can't get how the  wp_send_json_success($favorite_array);  can help me to sent data $favorite_array from the function.php file to fav_models.php

Comment: Just updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Yes, this is really a solution for transferring the variable to the fav_models.php But, unfortunately, my idea didn't work. I thought out the logic badly. I need to enable unregistered users to add models to favorites. But I was wrong, I cannot implement it this way. But thank you very much, I discovered for myself  wp_send_json_success/ wp_send_json_error functions.